# AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout not able to contain Button?

Tags: android, material-design, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am working with this following Repository here:

[CheeseSquare Repo via Chris Banes](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

Overall it is good repository but lacks complex layout schemes. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

[image]

Where the "DO SOMETHING" button is contained inside `AppBarLayout` and nested inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, and it collapses as you scroll up. That is my original thought, but it doesn't seem to give me the behavior I am looking for.

This is what my XML Layout looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <ImageView />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <Button/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton />
```

How would I go about accomplishing something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by implementing the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <!-- BUTTON INSERTED HERE -->
        <Button />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```