# Collapsing Toolbar. How to adapt custom Layout instead of default ImageView

Tags: android, android-animation, fadeout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to make **collasping toolbar, in which is my custom Layout** . On the image below is presented use of new released design.support lib. On the img.1, the element (ImageView) is disappearing. **In my project I want to disappear a Layout.**
Because inside Layout will be ViewPager it can not be resized like the image, it should dissolve in Toolbar background - should become transparent.

[image] img. 1

Additionaly I want to **open/hide** ToolbarLayout by moving ToolbarFooter - *belt to move* - bright blue Layout. So expand/collapse are not like in img.1 Instead it should **works like status bar** that shifts up and down by blick on ToolbarFooter.

[image] img.2

The think is I read about it a lot ([collapsing with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216336/appbarlayout-and-collapsingtoolbarlayout-not-able-to-contain-button) , [layout inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779123/need-to-disable-expand-on-collapsingtoolbarlayout-for-certain-fragments)) of but I've found any clue or implementation. I don't know how to approach to this topic. 
I suppose that my ViewPager and RelativeLayout(or whatever) should be outside of the toolbar. And they should just take a place of toolbar view like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_max_height"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/AppBarTheme">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:text="ToolbarTitle"                
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <net.android.app.views.ViewPagerToolbar
        android:id="@+id/calendar_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/app_bar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/belt_to_move"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/belt_to_move"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vp_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

Now can anyone tell me what component should I use?
Support library offers CoordinateLayout, CollapsedToolbar, Appbar.
By standard approach can be use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout which overlap view. So guys what you recommend me, how from which side should I eat this cake?

**UPDATED:**

Finally I've found the solution. It isn't CollapsingToolbar but ViewDragHelper.
The solution I followed: [Blog](http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2014/09/01/dragging-with-viewdraghelper/), [GitHub project](https://github.com/fedepaol/dragqueen), [YouTube explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI),

Comment: Have you checked out the [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) app? What exactly is your question? Are you running into a problem? Or is this just a blatant code request?

Comment: thank you for the answer, I changed a little bit the context of the question to make more clearly. This isn't complete answer for this question. In Cheesesquare project disappears the ImageView, I want use my custom Layout, that will not work when I place it instead ofImageView

Comment: Please attach full layout.xml file content.

Answer (score 1):

You need attach a viewPager above toolbar.
Example for ImageView :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="2dp">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:elevation="2dp"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="?attr/autoCompleteTextViewStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

 <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

             // put here your content

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:elevation="2dp"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe It will do the work, but you forgot about ToolbarFooter which will be used to expand / collapse Toolbar