# How to create bended Collapsing Toolbar Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How can we create a `collapsing toolbar` layout like Yahoo News Digest application ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use this tutorial. It helped me before. 

http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: this tutorial is on creating a layout with square/rectangular shaped . i.e. default one that is provided by google. But yahoo news app is not using this . check this : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.atom&hl=en

Comment: What's the exact thing you wanna do? You wanna implement the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with the bottom edge not parallel to the toolbar, or you wanna replicate the way Yahoo News Digest works (because it's not the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` the Yahoo app is using)?

Comment: Mainly I want to implement collapsingToolbarLayout with bottom edge not parallel to the toolbar. (if it is possible) . It will be also helpful if you can describe the method that yahoo is using (without CollapsingToolbarLayout as you have mentioned).

Comment: Check this out. It might useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101891/collapsing-toolbar-how-to-adapt-custom-layout-instead-of-default-imageview

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `app:behavior_overlapTop="50dp"` to your scrolling view? (This is the default behavior. Code can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java#L1143).)

Apparently, it should support that attribute to make the scrolling view overlap your app bar.

Start by implementing the square collapsing toolbar as you can find in many other guides and then set that parameter.

If that does not work, you could write your own `Behavior` I guess, inspiring from the one I [linked](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java#L1143) you (which is the default `AppBarLayout` behavior that allow the coordinator layout to collapse the top part.

To make the image not square you need to use a semi-transparent image or edit it by code.