# Why are my buttons' click areas too small inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-design-library

I've got three buttons inside a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. When expanded, the idea is to modify a filter on the image gallery being displayed, or pop up an edit dialog. I was getting inconsistent results–the buttons were only responding to clicks intermittently.

Eventually, I realized the issue was that the clickable area was much smaller than the client rect of the view. Horizontally, they seem normal, but vertically the clickable area is much shorter than the button. In the emulator I was able to get fairly precise as to the bounds:

[image: Zone of clickability]

You can touch them normally left to right, but top to bottom is wrong.

I have been trying to cobble together this layout from various snippets from the docs, official guides, online tutorials, and open source code examples. I don't fully understand how all the fancy support/design layouts work together, or what all of the configuration attributes exactly do when combined, so it's perfectly possible the fix will be a simple change of an attribute or two. Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?android:actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.CollapsingToolbar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="64dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnTags"
                             android:layout_width="64dp"
                             android:layout_height="64dp"
                             android:layout_weight="0.3"
                             android:src="@drawable/ic_tag"
                             android:tint="?android:attr/buttonTint"
                             android:background="@drawable/ripple" />

                <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnAlbums"
                             android:layout_width="64dp"
                             android:layout_height="64dp"
                             android:layout_weight="0.3"
                             android:src="@drawable/ic_albums"
                             android:tint="?android:attr/buttonTint"
                             android:background="@drawable/ripple" />

                <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnNewAlbum"
                             android:layout_width="64dp"
                             android:layout_height="64dp"
                             android:layout_weight="0.3"
                             android:src="@drawable/ic_new_album"
                             android:tint="?android:attr/buttonTint"
                             android:background="@drawable/ripple" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/LouvreTheme.ToolbarStyle"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <co.moonmonkeylabs.realmrecyclerview.RealmRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerAlbumGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="?android:attr/background"
        app:rrvLayoutType="Grid"
        app:rrvGridLayoutSpanCount="@integer/grid_span"
        app:rrvIsRefreshable="false"
        app:rrvSwipeToDelete="false" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then, in my `onViewCreated()` I assign each of the buttons an  OnClickListener. I can reliably and predictably trigger them, but only by clicking in that narrow vertical band pictured above.

Workaround and adjustments I have already tried:

- Switching from `ImageView`s to `FloatingActionButton`s, and finally `ImageButton`s
- Slapping `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on different views, including *all* of them
- Changing button dimensions from `wrap_content` to explicitly the size defined in the `VectorDrawable`s they are displaying
- Setting `android:minHeight` on the `LinearLayout` to the same explicit size as the buttons
- Making the `layout_weight` of each button 1.0, and setting the sum to 3.0
- Trying the `app:layout_collapseMode` variously as `paralax` and `none` on the `LinearLayout` that houses the buttons.

The only similar issue I've been able to find on SO is this: [AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout not able to contain Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216336/appbarlayout-and-collapsingtoolbarlayout-not-able-to-contain-button) No satisfactory answer was ever provided, just a workaround of moving the button outside of the collapsing area.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the Linear Layout shrunk because you have  android:paddingTop="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="64dp   -- you can test this by adding a color for the layout here android:background="@android:color/transparent"  to see what size it is --  if that is the case use Margins instead or wrap the Linear layout with a Relative layout eg Relative Layout --- Linear Layout --> your buttons

Comment: @Tasos Setting `android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"` on the `LinearLayout` actually turns the entire toolbar layout red, which is not what I would have expected. But it's definitely not cutting off in the middle in the buttons.

Comment: Ok. Try these settings in the LinearLayout and see if it helps  --- android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: Making it vertical, only the click region of the top icon is cut off. The ones below it are clickable over the entire visible area. Clearly something is weird when the expanded view is being laid out.

Comment: I haven't measured pixel perfect yet, but it looks like the region from the bottom of the status bar to the top of the clickable zone is the exact same height as the toolbar. That's gotta be a clue...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the `Toolbar` actually physically stays up at the top, despite appearing to stretch down with the expanded title text. It was thus partially covering the top two thirds or so of my buttons, which I couldn't tell because the toolbar background was set to transparent. By adding a contrasting background color to the toolbar, it became very obvious what was happening.

I found and tested two simple fixes:

1. add `android:layout_marginTop="?android:actionBarSize"` to the `LinearLayout` that was housing the buttons, so it is drawn below the toolbar, in the y direction.
2. swap the order of the toolbar and the buttons in the layout XML; the last one defined is drawn on top, and the buttons become fully clickable.

Comment: Why didn't you put the buttons as a toolbar menu in the first place?

Comment: Less control over placement and appearance, that way. There will eventually be a couple rows on them, with a layout and contents that might change based on app state.