# Cant click items inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've implemented the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that looks like this:

[image: collapsing toolbar layout]

It collapses when I scroll, however there's a big problem: I am unable to click items inside it (back button, edit button, edit text field etc). None of the items react to click/touch events.

Now, the "logic" sits in XML with the following structure:

```
    <CoordinatorLayout>
     <AppBarLayout>
     <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
     <RelativeLayout/> here's where the panel layout sits 
     <Toolbar/>
     <NestedScrollView/>

  //close tags as appropriate here
```

How do I make the items clickable (well, not by setting `android:clickable="true"` for sure)? Is it possible without writing listeners in `Java/Kotlin` code?

Comment: follow this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069549/why-are-my-buttons-click-areas-too-small-inside-a-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: Thanks @Ankita! Following the answer from this link I determined that my toolbar in fact stayed at the top and was overshadowing my buttons making them unclickable!

Comment: Then upvote me :P

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this XML attribute

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to your CollapsingToolbarLayout